# Speed control a requestAnimationFrame loop

Tags: javascript

I have got a method `method2` which is looping through some numbers, until it reaches the end and then it resets. However I need to control the speed of this. Within another method (`method1`) I loop through these numbers with mouse movement, I control this speed using the following:

```js
this.speedController += 1;
if (this.speedController < this.speed) {
    return;
}
if (this.speedController > this.speed) {
    this.speedController = 0;
}
```

How could I implement this into my `method2`, as i'd assume it would work just the same, however that loop doesn't run at all!

`method2`:

```js
spin(index) {
    let i = index;
    if (i >= this.images.length) {
        i = 1;
    }
    this.current = i;
    this.animationRequestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.spin(i));
    i += 1
},
```

## Edit:

Just attempted to use a timeout, however when stopping the animation I would have to clear the timeout and also run `clearAnimationFrame`, seems wrong.

```js
spin(index) {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        let i = index;
        if (i >= this.images.length) {
            i = 1;
        }
        this.current = i;
        this.animationRequestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.spin(i));
        i += 1
    }, this.speed * 10)
    
},
```

Comment: Hi! I think you should change `i += 1` to `this.current += 1` so that `current` counter would change after each cycle (if I have understood your question right)

Comment: Sorry I don't think I worded the question as that's not the issue haha. I have added an answer though as figured it out, thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find an answer and adapt it to my needs, for anyone else who is trying this, bare in mind this is a Vue component.

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            spinStart: null,
            spinThen: Date.now(),
            fps: 1000 / 5
        };
    },
    created() {
        if (this.animation) {
            this.spinStart = this.spinThen;
            this.spin(1);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        spin(index) {
            let i = index;
            if (i >= this.images.length) {
                i = 1;
            }
            this.animationRequestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.spin(i));

            let now = Date.now();
            let elapsed = now - this.spinThen;

            if (elapsed > this.fps) {

                this.spinThen = now - (elapsed % this.fps);

                this.current = i;
                i += 1;
            }
        },
```